# I want to build an app that provides user with an offline version of the online database

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

I tried using JSON by downloading and reading from it and it worked, though I wasn't able to save the file to the device, which is the major goal.

I don't want to use JSON. I want to read the data from MySQL database, not just echoing it with PHP script but also having it available offline.

Comment: how about using a local sqlite db

Comment: the offline db has to be gotten from the online db

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get information from online database directly to your phone. JSON is like English language for humans but for phones(devices). You must use it to send any type of information to your phone. Then you should use JsonReader class to parse(read) your json. Here is [official documentation for reading Json with JsonReader class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html).
After or during parsing your json you need to write information to your offline database SQLite. For this you need to follow [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html). Also there are a lot of examples in the Internet how to use SQLite database.
And there one thing, if you need load information to your offline database once and then read always from there, then just before sending json request, first check whether your database has information about that, if no - then request your json and save it. That's all. Hope it will help you. I tried to give you concept what you must do. The rest leaves to you.

Comment: Good luck with that. Our Android guy had to implement a custom json parser due to handset, *cough Samsung cough*, variance.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot.